# PyMongo- selecting sub-documents from collection by regex

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Lets take for example the following collections:

```
{
    '_id': '0',
    'docs': [
        {'value': 'abcd', 'key': '1234'},
        {'value': 'abef', 'key': '5678'}
    ]
}
{
    '_id': '1',
    'docs': [
        {'value': 'wxyz', 'key': '1234'},
        {'value': 'abgh', 'key': '5678'}
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to select only the sub-documents under the 'docs' list which 'value' contains the string 'ab'. What I'm expecting to get is the following collections:

```
{
    '_id': '0',
    'docs': [
        {'value': 'abcd', 'key': '1234'},
        {'value': 'abef', 'key': '5678'}
    ]
}
{
    '_id': '1',
    'docs': [
        {'value': 'abgh', 'key': '5678'}
    ]
}
```

Thus, filtering out the unmatched sub-documents.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an aggregation pipeline that matches each subdocument separately, then re-joins the matching subdocuments into arrays:

```
from pprint import pprint
from bson import Regex

regex = Regex(r'ab')
pprint(list(col.aggregate([{
    '$unwind': '$docs'
}, {
    '$match': {'docs.value': regex}
}, {
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$_id',
        'docs': {'$push': '$docs'}
    }
}])))
```

I assume "col" is a variable pointing to your PyMongo Collection object. This outputs:

```
[{u'_id': u'1', 
  u'docs': [{u'key': u'5678', u'value': u'abgh'}]},
 {u'_id': u'0',
  u'docs': [{u'key': u'1234', u'value': u'abcd'},
            {u'key': u'5678', u'value': u'abef'}]}]
```

The "r" prefix to the string makes it a Python "raw" string to avoid any trouble with regex code. In this case the regex is just "ab" so the "r" prefix isn't necessary, but it's good practice now so you don't make a mistake in the future.

Comment: This returns only the first match in a specific Collection. I need the selection to include any other matches, thus changing the output to include {'value': 'abef', 'key': '5678'}

Comment: Oh, good point. "find" can't do that until https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6612 is implemented, so I've updated my answer to use the aggregation framework instead.